# Alert when hitting submit

Tags: jquery, html

This is some pretty simplistic code and I'm not sure why it's not working.  I directly copied it from another HTML file I had and it works there but not on this file.

Here is the HTML for the form I have

```
<form>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Just a simple form for your email and password.  Now, I want there to be an alert when hitting submit.  This is the jQuery I wrote and copied from another HTML file I have where it works like a charm but not here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        alert( "String");
    });
</script>
```

I'm really confused as to why it doesn't work so any insight would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Check jquery.js  is loaded properly in your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your script inside document.ready

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        alert( "String");
    });
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        alert( "String");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Embed the code into $(document).ready() 
what it does is , it waits for the dom to be loaded properly and then loads the function so we have all functions available at the lifecycle

for this you can read

[W3schools Link for document.ready()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)

So your code should be

```
$document.ready(function(){
     $("form").submit(function(event){
        alert( "String");
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that when the javascript code is called before the document is loaded. If you are using jquery, you can simply add the javascript to  `$(function(){ ... })`

Here is the fiddle for example 1:  https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/joqrfeor/

Or if you just want to use it the way it works in your other file. Paste the script tag at the end of your file. i.e Before the `</body>` tag

Example 2:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <form>
       Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
       Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        alert( "String");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```